# i don't understand the prototype of unordered_set constructor

Tags: c++

in constructor of unordered_set :

```
explicit unordered_set ( size_type n = /* see below */,
                         const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                         const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                         const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type() );
```

i don't understand the line const hasher& hf = hasher()
what is hasher ? a fonctor ? and above all, what is hasher() ? a function that returns a fonctor ? i can't find the implementation of this function

Comment: What specifically is unclear from [the reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set) and examples there? Mind to cite and elaborate please?

Comment: Usually one always use default parameter and only specify types when declaring the template. However by using that design, it is possbile to have some flexibility by providing some state at construction time.

Comment: i did not understand that hasher() was the call of a constructor. I'm not used to the fact that classes names can start with a minuscule..that's what was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasher`, `key_equal`, and `allocator_type` are all template parameters with default types assigned in the declaration of the template class. For example, `hasher` defaults to `std::hash<Key>`:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class hasher = std::hash<Key>,
    class key_equal = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class allocator_type = std::allocator<Key>
> class unordered_set;
```

The lines such as `const hasher& hf = hasher()` are declaring a parameter of type `hasher` with a default value from the default constructor of the type (`hasher` in this case).

`hasher` and `key_equal` do happen to be functor types... but that is actually irrelevant for what you are looking at. Their constructors are being called, not the call operator.